# Google calendar?

Tags: android, google-api, calendar, google-calendar-api

I have a:

- Mail : -------@gmail.com
- Password : ---------
- Public google calendar with public events

I want an app (with username and password in the code) to show my calendar events to all the people who wants.

Any help? Thanks

Comment: in other words that is. It is an application in which there are many functions, one of which is consult the calendar of activities of this site. Linked to Google Calendar

Comment: @noogui. The android quickstart example